# Why is a file tested with -r not readable by cat?

Tags: bash

I have a cron job with the following two lines in it:

```
LOCK=/var/run/dns-check
...
if [ ! -r "$LOCK" -o "$ADDR_NOW" != "$(cat $LOCK)" ] ; then
```

It is the only use of `cat` in the script. Today I got a mail from cron with the following error:

```
cat: /var/run/dns-check: No such file or directory
```

I am wondering what has happened here.

I am testing the file with `-r` to check if it is readable and negate the result. This means, if the file is not readable the check succeeds. The evaluation can stop here, because the expression is already true. `cat` will not be called.

Otherwise the `-o` condition is evaluated, which means, if the file is there, `cat` is executed.

Why does `cat` report the error, that the file can not be read, although `test -r` found out that it is readable?

Comment: Is it important to draw a distinction between "`$LOCK` isn't readable" and "`$LOCK` is empty"? If not, you can just use `[ "$ADDR_NOW" != "$(cat "$LOCK" 2> /dev/null)" ]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The form of conditional you're using doesn't do short-circuit evaluation.  Instead, try this:

```
[ ! -r "$LOCK" ] || [ "$ADDR_NOW" != "$(cat $LOCK)" ]
```

Then the second check will only occur if the first fails.

Comment: What should change between the left and right side of an or? Nobody else but this cron job is using the file.

Comment: cron doesn't semm to create it so anything else is actually using the file.

Comment: @ceving: I see.  I updated my answer with this new knowledge.  I think it will solve your problem now.

Comment: Of course! `test` is only command and all arguments have to be passed to the command before it can be evaluated. No chance for short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: If you are actually using `bash` (and not in POSIX mode) you can use `[[ ! -r $LOCK || $ADDR_NOW != "$(cat $LOCK)" ]]` and it will short-circuit as expected.

Comment: @chepner: absolutely.  Though when I discovered the POSIX way I was pretty happy to avoid the Bashism.  Also IMO the Bashism is more likely to get broken by a wayward maintenance programmer...maybe the POSIX one is too though.  :(